# Show that $\frac{4x}{(x+1)^2 + y^2} \leq 1$.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I am writing a longer proof and the last thing I want to show (I hope this is correct) is that
$$ 0 < \frac{4x}{(x+1)^2 + y^2} \leq 1 \qquad \forall x,y\in\Bbb R^+$$

The $0 <$ part is trivial but I am stuck with the other one. Also, I must not use $\lim$ for the proof because this has not been taught yet.

Comment: If $x=1$ and $y=-2$, the inequality doesn't hold.

Comment: He probably means $y>0$ as well?

Comment: @Marty Cohen: What a coincidence but my solution is little weaker than yours because I supposed $y$ is positive :)

Comment: @user284331 my solution is not bad too :)

Comment: There was a typo in my initial post. I meant $y^2$ and not $y$. (so yes, $y$ is positive) I am so sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y$ must be positive as commented above or the term is probably $y^2$. In both cases it is true. Since $(x-1)^2=x^2-2x+1\geq 0$ and hence adding $4x$ to both sides give $x^2+2x+1\geq 4x$ or $(x+1)^2\geq 4x$. Taking reciprocal we get $\frac{4x}{(x+1)^2}\leq 1$. Thus we have $0<\frac{4x}{(x+1)^2+y}\leq\frac{4x}{(x+1)^2}\leq 1$.

Answer (score 4):

If you assume that
$y \ge 0$,
the upper bound is
equivalent to
$4x \le (x+1)^2
=x^2+2x+1$
or,
subtracting $4x$
from both sides,
$0 \le x^2-2x+1
=(x-1)^2
$
which is true.

Comment: Thank you. But I accepted another answer that started with an obviously correct statement ($0 \leq (x-1)^2$). (+1)

Answer (score 1):

I do not think this holds, take:

$x=1$, and $y=-100$

Your expression is less than $0$.

**EDIT**

OP changes the condition, which makes it to be true now. I’ll not repeat, as there is an answer for that already.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, if $x=1$, $y=-4$, the expression is not even defined.

After the edited version, then @marty cohen provided a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

The claim is false for $\left(\frac 52, -5\right)$.